# how to set onclick attribute in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am building a table with text in the first column and buttons that do stuff in the second column.  Here is the complete .js file:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

var row = table.insertRow(i);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell.innerHTML = text[i];

var cell = row.insertCell(1);
var cellElement = document.createElement("input");
cellElement.setAttribute("id", ID[i]);  
cellElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
cellElement.setAttribute("value", "button");

/////cellElement.onclick =
     /////function(){ doThisThing(i,ID[i]); } );

cell.appendChild(cellElement);
row.appendChild(cell);

}

table.appendChild(tableBody);

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Everything works except for the cellEllement.onclick = function(){};  The onlick() function does not set.  I have tried variations on this:

```
cellElement.setAttribute("onclick",doThisThing(i,ID[i]));
```

How to I set the button onclick attribute when looping through to create a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a reference to the `i` variable inside your function which will continue to change with the loop, and won't hold the value of `i` that it has when you go through that iteration of the loop. You need to hold on to the current value of `i`, probably by wrapping your callback in another function:

```
cellElement.onclick = (function(currI) {
   return function() { doThisThing(currI, ID[currI]); };
})(i);
```

You could also use `bind` to make things simpler:

```
cellElement.onclick = doThisThing.bind(null, i, ID[i]);
```

Comment: I was not able to get the first one to work passing the ID parameter, however, this worked when passing only the integer argument.  I had to change my original function but got it to work thanks!  Also you have an extra ")" in your answer.